# javascript check for a special character at the beginning a string

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to get a value from input field.

I want to check if the string has % or * at the beginning of the string then show an alert.

Comment: Up voting, it is a valid question to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (/^[%*]/.test(document.getElementById("yourelementid").value))
   alert("Where can I find a JavaScript tutorial?");
```

By way of explanation: the regular expression `/^[%*]/` means:

```
^       match the beginning of the string, followed immediately by
[%*]    any one of the characters inside the brackets
```

Testing the entered value against that regex will return true or false.

Comment: Thanks, but both values might or might not come at the same time. Three case, either %, either * or both

Comment: There aren't three cases. Your question says "if the string has % or * at the beginning of the string then show an alert" - which means "if the first character of the string is % or * then show an alert". It doesn't matter if both characters appear, because still one or the other will be the first character - which is what my answer tests for.

Answer (score 3):

getElementById(ID).value.charAt(0);

I'm sure you can figure out the rest.  Please do some research first as things like this should be really easy to find by googling it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substring method, for example:

```
data.substring(0, 1) === '%'

if(data.substring(0, 1) === '%' || data.substring(0, 1) === '*')
{ 
   alert("Not allowed"); 
}
```

or you can try the regex way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the `indexOf` method of strings.

```
var s = "%kdjfkjdf";
if (s.indexOf("%") == 0 || s.indexOf("*") == 0)
{
   // do something
}
```

You can also use regular expressions too as pointed out in @nnnnnn's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to below link.

[javascript pattern matching](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re2.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="%*hkfhkasdfjlkjasdfjkdas";

if(str.indexOf("%") === 0|| str.indexOf("*") === 0){
alert("true");
}
else{
alert("false");
}
```

please check fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/RPxMS/

you can also use `prototype` plugin for javascript which contains method `startWith`.

```
if(str.startWith("%"))
{
// do
}
```

check the details in the link:  [click here](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/String/prototype/startsWith/)